# Consuming a REST Service with SAS

Tags: rest, sas

This is sort of an odd question.  I know that SAS has a PROC SOAP for consuming web services.  I wonder if anyone has any experience consuming XML from a REST resource using SAS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Base SAS 9.2 there is also a new proc called [proc http](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a003286672.htm). It was designed specifically to call REST services (or for site scraping). You could also use the url access method for simple get requests. The advantage of **proc http** is that you can control the http verb used and also pass a payload.

Comment: awesome! Thank you.  Looks a bit easier to use than filename url as well!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had specific experience with REST APIs from SAS, but I've worked with similar web-based services.

You can use the *filename url* engine to access arbitrary URLs and read the results back.  YMMV as far as compatibility with particular REST APIs and XML output goes.

Alternatively, you could use system calls to programs like *wget* or *curl* to download the XML into a file, then parse the input using SAS' xml engine.

Comment: Thanks Rog, In most cases I only want to retrieve a string so maybe filename url will be enough for me.